# Is it possible to get old Vanguard cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, online

If you start Magic Online today, is there a way to acquire Vanguard cards that do not come with the client but have been released in the past? Can they be bought or traded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they can be traded.

I don't believe they are sold by Wizards, when I used to play they were given as tournament or set release perks.

Ah, looks like nowadays new players [get a booster pack](http://www.wizards.com/magic/tcg/article.aspx?x=magic/magiconline/vanguard) of default Vanguard cards.